# 'Each student has the same distance to school' is this correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs

I want to describe a situation like this: There are two students. One of them has to walk 1 km to school, the other the same. Should I say:

> Each student has the same distance to school.

or

> Each student is the same distance to school.

or

> Each student is at the same distance to school.

or

> Each student is of the same distance to school.

Or do you have a better way of saying this?

Answer (score 4):

> do you have a better way of saying this?

Here are some examples:

> Each student is the same distance from (the) school.
>
> Each student has to walk the same distance to (the) school.

Anyway, the choice of prepositions like "of" or "at" is not always obvious.